# WSO2 API Manager - Publisher - Too many redirects

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up an API Manager 1.10 cluster, with each component in a separate VM, by following this guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+1.10.0 fronted by a nginx proxy in Azure.

All the components starts up fine (installed as a service) but only the store 'works'. I cannot access publisher in publisher node (& store node) or carbon page in the gateway nodes. I get TOO MANY redirects error on the browser.

Is there anyway I can debug the issue to see whats is going wrong? The traffic is hitting the box but I get the following error:

```
The xxxxxx.co.uk page isn’t working

xxxxx.co.uk redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

To be clear:

- store.blue13.com/store - works
- store.blue13.com/publisher- doesn't work (gets the above error)
- publisher.blue13.com/publisher- doesn't work  (gets the above error)
- publisher.blue13.com/store - works
- gateway.blue13.com/carbon- doesn't work  (gets the above error)

I am not quite sure what I am missing.

Access logs from the Publisher box:

```
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/site/pages/login.jag?requestedPage=https://xxxx.co.uk/publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/site/pages/login.jag?requestedPage=https://xxxx.co.uk/publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/site/pages/login.jag?requestedPage=https://xxxxx.co.uk/publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
[30/Mar/2017:10:47:21 +0000] "GET /publisher/site/pages/login.jag?requestedPage=https://xxxxx.co.uk/publisher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

As you can see its just goes on a redirect loop. I have followed the [steps here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+a+Reverse+Proxy+Server) in setting up the reverse proxy.

EDIT:

All static pages works fine, only pages with login forms in them goes on a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was in the syntax on site.json:

```
/wso2/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/site/conf/site.json
/wso2/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json
/wso2/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin/site/conf/site.json
```

I had removed some commas.